# Problem with variations!

Tags: combinatorics

$$A = {0,1,2,3,5,6}$$
I have to find all even five-digit numbers using the digits from A without repeating the digits. Can you help me, please?

Answer (score 2):

What digits can even numbers end with?

What digits can 5-digit numbers start with?

Once you've picked the start and the end, what do you still have to pick (and from how many digits) to fill in the middle?

Comment: They can end with 0,2,6.
They only can't begin with zero.
I have to pick 3 numbers from 4 left digits.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: It’s probably easiest to split the computation into two cases, depending on whether the first digit is odd or even.

1. The first digit is odd. There are $3$ ways to choose the first digit. All three even digits are still available, so there are $3$ ways to choose the last digit. Now how many ways are there to choose the three digits in the middle?
2. The first digit is even. There $2$ ways to choose the first digit. Only two even digits are still available.